# JavaScript prompt() firing before content is rendered

Tags: javascript, prompt

This is my first time working with prompt(). I have completed the assignment to the specifications given by the teacher, however I am really annoyed that the prompt() gets called before the content in the background gets called (I even used `window.onload = function() {blah};` but it still gets called before the content is displayed.

The link to the page is http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~csoultz/ and click on lab4

This is not a huge concern more so a curiosity of mine. I have been researching it for the last few hours and have found nothing. I don't want to load anymore libraries and if it is not possible without a library please let me know. Thank you in advance for any help

here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Work Week Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mySite.css">

<script>
function askquestion(question,answer){
  var userAnswer = prompt(question.toString());
  if(userAnswer!=null) return userAnswer.toLowerCase()===answer.toLowerCase();
};
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>A Simple Quiz</h1>
  <p><output id="result"></output></p>
  <script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var trivia=[["Which is the most widely spoken language in the world?","Mandarin"],
                ["The art of paper folding is known as what?","Origami"],
                ["Bubble tea originated in which country?","Taiwan"]
              ];
    var correct=0;
    var total=trivia.length;
    for(i=0;i<trivia.length;i++){
      if(askquestion(trivia[i][0],trivia[i][1])){
        alert("Correct!");
        correct++;
      }
      else{
        alert("Sorry. The correct answer is "+trivia[i][1].toString());
      }
    }
    var resultElement = document.getElementById("result");
    resultElement.innerHTML = "You got "+correct.toString()+" out of "+total.toString()+" questions correct";
  };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which content in the background do you want to appear before the prompt? Is it the backround with "You got X correct?"

Comment: If you visit the live site (http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~csoultz/) then click on the link to lab4 the prompt() shows up while still on the page that links to the page in question

Comment: No it is the blue of the page and the h1 tag

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a timeout?

Comment: I see the background & title before the prompt, so not sure...  NB: jQuery `ready` will trigger before `windown.onload`, so that will not improve it.

Comment: No.....how do you do a javascript timeout?

Comment: `setTimeout(function () { // do something }, 1000);`

Comment: I am using chrome if that matters....should I try a different browser?

Comment: `setTimeout(function, timeout)`, possibly just set a short timeout so it loads then JS executes?

Comment: Thank you trincot that works

Comment: An example @cody-soultz: https://jsbin.com/yodicoruje/edit?output

Comment: Is there a way to mark as solved? I would rather not use a blind timeout function, but if that is the best way then so be it.

Comment: It seems specific to Chrome. FF does not have this behaviour, and I think Chrome is wrong. `window.onload` should only trigger when all is loaded, including even images and stuff.

Comment: Would this be a bug that I should report to chromium?

Comment: I assume `window.addEventListener("load")` has the same issue?

Comment: Q1, answer is Mandarin

Comment: I found all three questions at http://trivia.fyi/

Comment: @PaulS. I did change my answer to part 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to wrap my function in a setTimeout with a timeout value of 10 and the issue was fixed in chrome.

```
window.onload = setTimeout(function() {
                                       //Do Stuff Here
                           },10);
```